# Show only Months in Quicksight

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Im new with Quicksight- but for this basic thing I want I have searched the whole web and didnt find the answer.

What I want: Count the 2nd col for each month (total 12 rows).

What happend actually: Its counting the 2nd col well- but for each month in EACH year I have in the DB (which is tens!)
How can I group all the month so it will be only 12 for whole the years?

This is how it looks:
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to use the countOver function to do that. Create a calculated field that should look something like:

```
countOver({id}, [Bday month], PRE_AGG)
```

Obviously you might need to adapt it with your exact columns name.